# Generate a neshan map link based on coordinates

Tags: navigator, neshan, neshan-map, neshan-platform, neshan-android-sdk

how can I generate a map link for Neshan app from a location coordinates like google map?

[https://www.google.com/maps/place/{lat},{lug}](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%7Blat%7D,%7Blug%7D)

something like this:
https://nshn.ir/maps/place/36.2961,59.6141

please help

Answer (score 0):

I found this work after some test....

[https://maps.neshan.org/@{lat},{lung}](https://maps.neshan.org/@%7Blat%7D,%7Blung%7D)
like:
https://maps.neshan.org/@36.2961,59.6141,16.0z,0.0p

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I was able to solve my problem using this method.

```
href={ isAndroid()
     ? `intent://nshn.ir/?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}#Intent;scheme=http;package=org.rajman.neshan.traffic.tehran.navigator;S.browser_fallback_url=https://nshn.ir/?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng};end`
     : `https://nshn.ir/?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}`
                }
```

```
const isAndroid = () => {
  const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return userAgent.includes('android');
};
```

also you can use

```
android —> nshn:47.6,-122.3
ios —> neshan://?ll=36.30776,59.55403
```

‍‍‍